# Sequelize find two users in same group

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

```
user_id | group_id
------------------
 5         3
 6         1
 6         3
 7         1
 7         2
 8         2
```

My join table looks like this. The query I'm trying to accomplish is finding if two user_ids have a matching group_id.

I don't need any specific information back from the query, just a simple true or false.

Comment: You didn't mention the two tables and the query that you are applying. Always post complete details to get right answers.

Comment: If two *given* `user_id`s, or if any two `user_id`s?

Comment: If two given user_ids

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select 
    (select group_id from tbl where user_id = 'user_id1')
    <=>
    (select group_id from tbl where user_id = 'user_id2');
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'sequelize'?